# Correct definition of gradient (and divergence) on smooth manifolds (for engineers)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am very sorry if this is a very trivial question or my formulation is inadequate, I am only an engineer, and I am not familiar with the topic. I am looking for the definition of the gradient of a function $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ being on a $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold $M = \{x | m(x) = 0\}$ defined through a real valued and differentiable scalar function $m(x) = 0 \in \mathbb{R}^1$. The vector $f(x)$ is not necessarily tangent to $M$. After some reading I found the definition of an "intrinsic gradient" of a function $f(x)$ on $M$ through orthogonal projection
\begin{equation}
\nabla_M f(x) = J - \left(\frac{J\mu}{||\mu||^2}\right) \otimes \mu
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
J = \nabla_x f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}\ , \quad
\mu = \nabla_x m(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}
\end{equation}
and $\otimes$ being the dyadic product.

Is this $\nabla_M f(x)$ the quantity which tells me how $f(x)$ from point to point on the manifold changes? I can interpret this more or less by the perspective that the total change of $f(x)$ at $x$ is described by its normal gradient, but the change **relevant** to the points on the manifold is described by the part of the gradient tangential to the manifold. So the orthogonal projection filters the relevant part.

**Question: Is this interpretation and definition correct? If not, could you recommend any literature for starting with this topic?**

Actually, I have to understand the gradients (and divergence, for which I am also not sure of its definition) of functions defined on the manifold of rotational matrices $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3} $ in 3D, $M = \{Q | QQ^T=1_3 \wedge \det(Q)=1 \}$ with $1_3$ being the identity matrix in 3D. But before that I need to be sure that I understand first the easy stuff. Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**
I just thought a little more and I dont know if the following definition of the divergence on a manifold is sensible and already defined. For $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ I know that the divergence is defined as
\begin{equation}
{\rm div}{(f(x))} 
= (\nabla_x f(x)) \cdot 1_n 
= \sum_{\alpha=1}^n \frac{\partial f_\alpha}{\partial x_\alpha}
= \sum_{\alpha=1}^n (\nabla_x f(x))\cdot(e_\alpha \otimes e_\alpha)
\end{equation}
with arbitrary orthonormal basis vectors $\{e_\alpha\}$. For a manifold $M = \{x|m(x)=0\}$ the matrix
\begin{equation}
1_M = 1_n - \frac{\mu}{||\mu||}\otimes\frac{\mu}{||\mu||} , \quad
\mu = \nabla_x m(x)
\end{equation}
represents the sum of the dyadic products of $(n-1)$ orthonormal tangential vectors $\tau_\alpha$ of the $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold at $x$, so
\begin{equation}
{\rm div}_M(f(x)) 
= (\nabla_M f(x)) \cdot 1_M
= \sum_{\alpha=1}^{n-1} (\nabla_M f(x)) \cdot (\tau_\alpha\otimes\tau_\alpha)
\end{equation} 
would give me the sum of the relevant changes of $f(x)$ in the different orthonormal tangential directions at $x$ on the manifold. This definition turns out (after some calculations) to be 
\begin{equation}
{\rm div}_M(f(x)) 
= (\nabla_M f(x)) \cdot 1_M
= {\rm div}(f(x)) - \frac{\mu}{||\mu||} \cdot \left( (\nabla_x f(x)) \frac{\mu}{||\mu||} \right)
\end{equation}
**Is this the correct definition of the divergence on a manifold?** This idea is for me geometrically intuitive **but** from a physical point of view I don't like it since singular points (wells and sinks) **on the manifold** for which the original divergence vanishes may **not** be identified as singular points on the manifold. I am aware that playing on a manifold of a bigger space inevitably will be blind to information orthogonal to it, but such a loss of information somehow troubles me.

Comment: Hang on, in the beginning of the question you stated both that $f$ is a real-valued function and $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that $f(x)$ is a vector with real valued components, so $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with real-valued components $f_i(x) \in \mathbb{R}$. The divergence is only defined for vectors, right?

Comment: divergence is only defined for _tangent vectors_. You need that when $x\in M$, $f(x)$ is tangent to $M$ at the point $x$.

Comment: If the divergence is only defined for tangent vectors at a point on a set, then the definition I came up in my question would be fine, or not? That's the question.

Comment: *If* you assume $f(x)$ is tangent to $M$, then yes, the definition you wrote is fine, and is the same as the standard one from Riemannian geometry. You have not made that assumption in your question.

Comment: I did not, because I have to treat general functions not necessarily tangent to $M$. But thanks for the information, I did not know that.